# Assigning an ajax fetch function to a variable returns undefined even though data definitely returns?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a data fetch function `getAvailableDates` that I call by assigning a variable `AVAILABLE_DATES`, in the `done` callback I log out the response and my data is there but returning the data and logging out the variable returns `undefined`. Can anyone explain where I might be going wrong with this?

```
define([
    'jquery'
], function (
    $
) {

    "use strict";

    function getAvailableDates() {
        console.log('Running getAvailableDates');

        var requestAvailableDates = $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: 'api/dcgdates',
            data: JSON.stringify(requestAvailableDates),
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json"
        });

        requestAvailableDates.done(function(data) {
            console.log('getAvailableDates success', data);
            return data;
        });
    }

    return {

        DATE_FORMAT: "dd M yy",
        AVAILABLE_DATES: getAvailableDates()
    };
});
```

Comment: Because your log execute before the data is fetched.

Comment: Oh, how can I delay this?

Comment: You need to use callbacks.. you can't `return` from an AJAX call

Comment: Can you show me an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [deferred](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/) return by the $.ajax, as you use it to log the data, its chainable, you can write:

```
var request = $.ajax(...);
// This will return the deferred object. And you can keep call `.done` on it to chain the callbacks.
return request.done(...).done(...);
```

All of the callbacks chained by `.done` will receive the same data from your ajax request.

```
define(['jquery'], function($) {
    "use strict";
    function getAvailableDates() {
        console.log('Running getAvailableDates');

        var requestAvailableDates = $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: 'api/dcgdates',
            data: JSON.stringify(requestAvailableDates),
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json"
        });

        // Return a deferred object.
        return requestAvailableDates.done(function(data) {
            console.log('getAvailableDates success', data);
            return data;
        });
    }

    return {
        DATE_FORMAT: "dd M yy",
        deferredObj: getAvailableDates()
    };
});
```

Then you can get the object and use :

```
returnObj.deferredObj.done(function(data) {
   // do something......
});
```

To get its value.

Below is a snippet to show how you can use it.

```js
var test = function() {
  var dfd = $.Deferred();  
  
  setTimeout(function() {
    dfd.resolve(1);
  }, 3000);
  
  // Each .done returns the deferred object, which can be chained to more callbacks.
  // And they'll execute in the order you chained them.
  return dfd
    .done(function(val) {
        console.log(val);
     })
    .done(function(val) {
        console.log('another ' + val);
     });
  

};

var deferred = test();

// The return deferred object can keep chaining to get the value.
// You can write your logic here to handle the data when deferred resolved.
deferred.done(function(val) {
  console.log('I got the same value: ' + val);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```